# Sql últimos ids

Tags: php, sql

Como faço para retornar os 5 últimos id com sql?
ID NOME
1 João
2 Guilherme
3 Alberto
4 Alexandre
5 Michael
6 Lucas

E vai retornar:
2 Guilherme
3 Alberto
4 Alexandre
5 Michael
6 Lucas

Comment: use o `limit(0,5)` e `order by desc` isso deve resolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenta:

```
SELECT * FROM Usuarios
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Utilizando `PDO`:

```
$pdo = new PDO('... seus dados ...');
$consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT id, nome FROM Usuarios ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5");

while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "Nome: {$linha['nome']} - ID: {$linha['id']}<br />";
}
```

Comment: E como faço isso em PDO? Retornado o username

Comment: @misakie Atualizado, da uma olhada

Comment: Resolvido! Obrigado Maicon Carraro